# Does GBWhatsapp's back up feature restore media/images INSIDE all the chats?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I know that GBWhatsapp's inbuilt backup feature restores all chats and media safely. However, what is important to me is to be able to see all the media of a chat from *within the chat itself* (the one you get when you open a chat header).

I have many groups and chats who's media images I need to access quickly from within the chat and I need to know if the images stay in the chat media. Can anyone who uses GBWA verify this?

As a side question, if the above isn't possible, is there any other way to backup my app in such a manner as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it, it does. A normal backup backs up all media within a chat too.